# Ending a sentence with abbreviation and ellipses

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations

When using an abbreviation at the end of a sentence, such as "etc." and a ellipses, would you use three or four periods?

Comment: Neither, you'd use a period and an ellipsis, which is a character in and of itself. But, if for whatever reason, the character is unavailable, you'd use three dots to indicate the ellipsis, bringing the number of periods at the end of your sentence to four. Oh, and it totally doesn't matter if the final word is an abbreviation. If you are truly _ending_ a sentence with an ellipsis (dialog notwithstanding), you'd still use an ellipsis (to indicate the trailing off/exclusion) and a period (to indicate the end of the sentence).

Comment: Can you provide a specific example?